# How to set background image inside of text

Tags: android, image, background, textview, drawable

Can anybody tell me how to set background image inside  of text? (not textview background image) 
Is that possible to do that with drawable or create custom view.
Like this : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CJHcYUuBY1M/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: background color of text or color of text?

Comment: Can you elaborate on IMAGE OF ANY TEXT??

Comment: Like this : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CJHcYUuBY1M/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Background image inside text @Kaushal

Comment: You can use Canvas or BitmapShader. Look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791012/android-textured-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use Shader class for this purpose. Here is the sample code:

```
    Bitmap bitmapObj  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.your_image);
    Shader shaderObj = new BitmapShader(bitmapObj,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    textViewObj.getPaint().setShader(shaderObj);
    textViewObj.setText("hello");
```

For more methods, refer [Docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html)