# in Android, can I fill text with an image instead of a color?

Tags: android, textview

In PowerPoint it's easy to fill text with an image instead of just a color.  Here's an example:

[image: styled text with kitten image as background]

I'm building a custom TextView in Android and would like to reproduce this same effect.  I haven't had success searching Android documentation, Stack Overflow or Google.  Does anyone have a clue how I can accomplish this?  In a perfect work I'd do something like:

`paint.setcolor(bounds, Bitmap kitten)`

Comment: Do you know how PowerPoint does it? Maybe if you could replicate the behaviour if you know how it works (I have no idea about how it could be done).

Comment: Try this https://www.android-examples.com/add-set-bitmapshader-texture-effect-on-textview-text-in-android/

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14791012/9134576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android textured text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791012/android-textured-text)

Comment: What @Nas proposed seems really good. There is a chance that it will work with that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Xfermode.DST_IN will help.

You need to use canvas api, first render the back-ground, then the text. and use `setXfermode()`. Example:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawARGB(255, 139, 197, 186);

    int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
    int layerId = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        int r = canvasWidth / 3;

        paint.setColor(0xFFFFCC44);
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        paint.setColor(0xFF66AAFF);
        canvas.drawRect(r, r, r * 2.7f, r * 2.7f, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.restoreToCount(layerId);
}
```

[image]